# How do these PTX instructions accelerate cuda applications?

Tags: cuda

In cuda 11 we have `cp.async` to load data from GMEM to SMEM and `ldmatrix.sync` to move data from SMEM to register. How do those instructions help us? by vectorizing?

Comment: The asynchronicity lets you do work while waiting for the memory transfer to shared memory. See [this blog post](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/controlling-data-movement-to-boost-performance-on-ampere-architecture/).

Comment: Concerning ldmatrix.sync: As most of us are not NVIDIA employees, we dont really know whats going on under the hood. Since you are loading data from shared memory into multiple registers for a whole warp in a very specific pattern, I guess you can optimize this data access quite a lot. But afaik NVIDIA really only tell us what it does, and not how (see [PTX Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#warp-level-matrix-instructions-ldmatrix))

Comment: GPUs don’t run PTX. For all we know it is compiled down into many instructions by the assembler and there is no actual hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new, asynchronous, copy-to-share-mem instructions help us by freeing the warp which issues the instruction to execute other instructions in parallel to the copying.

Of course, this is mostly useful if the warp has such instructions to execute which aren't other loads from global memory. So, arithmetic, special functions, random number generation, etc. etc.

The matrix-load instructions are useful w.r.t. matrix operations. Recent NVIDIA GPUs have specialty hardware for performing matrix  operations multiplication ("tensor cores"). These are obviously faster than performing these with the GPU's general-purpose hardware. To use the matrix ops, one needs to load data into specialty registers, and that's what the `ldmatrix` instructions do.